# Set multiple form values using jQuery Data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, custom-data-attribute

1. So let us say i have a form with id #form which has two input fields, namely title & price.
2. I click on the Edit button somewhere in the application which has data attributes (e.g data-title="Apple" data-price="10")that are to be assigned to the #form upon clicking the button.
3. the obvious solution that works is
   `$("#name").val($(this).data('name')); 
   $("#price").val($(this).data('price'));`
4. This obviously looks bad when you have too many fields. So I am trying to get something like this to work **`$('#form').data($(this).data());`**, **more or less in a single like**
5. Have tried this many ways with no success

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You need to be more specific. Your question have to contain at least a complete HTML example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a jquery plugin that you can call from the element that contains the data points and have it apply the data based on the key to elements within the form of that same name. Example below

```
$.fn.applyData = function(form) {
    $form = $(form);
    $.each($(this).data(), function(i, key) {
        $form.find('#' + i).val(key);
    });
};
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LCM8S/43/

Comment: this one works but I was trying to get something like `$('#form').data($(this).data());` or does jquery does not support that to work